# AngularJS apply filters on data previously filtered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a `$scope.users` that I use to show a table and I need to apply a filter with multiple options,

Here is the `$scope.users` object:

```
[
  {
    "login": "andres.un1@mail.com",
    "merchant": {
      "merchantId": 500095,
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "defaultAccountId": null,
      "accounts": {
        "500092": "ADMIN",
        "500178": "CONSULT",
        "500180": "ADMIN",
        "500182": "ADMIN",
        "500201": "ADMIN"
      }
    },    
    "name": "Carlos"    
  },
  {
    "login": "andres.un2@mail.com",
    "merchant": {
      "merchantId": 500095,
      "status": "DISABLED",
      "defaultAccountId": null,
      "accounts": {
        "500092": "CONSULT",
        "500178": "MANAGER",
        "500180": "ADMIN",
        "500182": "ADMIN",
        "500201": "ADMIN"
      }
    },
    "name": "Carlos Andres"
  },
  {
    "login": "cosme.fulanito@mail.com",
    "merchant": {
      "merchantId": 500095,
      "status": "DISABLED",
      "defaultAccountId": null,
      "accounts": {
        "500092": "CONSULT",
        "500178": "MANAGER",
        "500180": "ADMIN",
        "500182": "ADMIN",
        "500201": "ADMIN"
      }
    },
    "name": "Cosme"    
  }
]
```

In the filter I pass other object from the `$scope` to filter the data, in this case is `$scope.searchParams` that I previously calculate in a directive.

`$scope.searchParams`:

```
{
  "name": [
    "arl"
  ],
  "login": [
    "@"
  ],
  "merchant.status": [
    "ENABLED"
  ],
  "merchant.accounts": [
    "501678",
    "501675",
    "MANAGER",
    "ADMIN"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, `name` and `login` are unique in the filter, but `status` and `account` can have multiple values to apply in the filter. Here is my approach to do that but I think is very ineffective, it is important that each filter is applied on the data previously filtered by another filter:

```
var usrUser = function () {

  var SEPARATOR = '.';

  return function (users, filters) {

    // when the filter is not defined shows all results
    if(filters === undefined || angular.equals({}, filters)){
      return users;
    }

    var matchName = function (element){
      if(element['name'].indexOf(filters['name']) >= 0){
        return element;
      }
    };

    var matchLogin = function (element){
      if(element['login'].indexOf(filters['login']) >= 0){
        return element;
      }
    };

    var matchState = function (element){
      if(filters['merchant.status'].indexOf(element['merchant']['status']) >= 0){
        return element;
      }
    };

    var matchAccount = function (element){
      var match = false;
      angular.forEach(element['merchant']['accounts'], function(profile, accountId){
        if(filters['merchant.accounts'].indexOf(accountId) >= 0 ||
          filters['merchant.accounts'].indexOf(profile) >= 0){
          match = true;
          return;
        }
      });
      if(match){
        return element;
      }
    };

    if(filters['name'] !== undefined){
      users = users.filter(matchName);
    }

    if(filters['login'] !== undefined){
      users = users.filter(matchLogin);
    }

    if(filters['merchant.status'] !== undefined){
      users = users.filter(matchState);
    }

    if(filters['merchant.accounts'] !== undefined){
      users = users.filter(matchAccount);
    }

    return users;
  };
};
//-- register filter
angular.module('users').filter('usrUser', usrUser);
```

Finally here is how I am using the fiter: `<tbody ng-repeat="user in users | secUser:searchParams " class="table-striped">`

Is there a better way to implement this filter considering that in the future there can be more filter fields? Also I think is very coupled with the view.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work here? Are you just looking for code review/advice?

Comment: Yeah @NicolasMoise, it is very coupled to the view. If I pass more fields I'll have to add another filter function.

Comment: You should post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ then, this is too opinion-based for SO and is not likely to help anybody.

Comment: @NicolasMoise, thanks here is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143217/angularjs-apply-filters-on-data-previously-filtered